# PrimeFaces 4.0 selectOneMenu-ajax-call works with GlassFish 4.0, but not with Tomcat 7.0.27?

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, primefaces, glassfish

I've developed a Java7 EE Web-Project on my local machine, using GlassFish 4.0 and PrimeFaces 4.0. I've successfully deployed it via .war-file on my WebServer, running Apache Tomcat 7.0.27. 
Everything works identical, except this little code-snippet:

```
...

<h:form id="autoComplete">
    <p:autoComplete id="auto" size="55" converter="autoConverter" value="#{autoComplete.indexObj}" var="per" itemLabel="#{per.name}"  itemValue="#{per.id}" completeMethod="#{autoComplete.complete}" onkeydown="styleOnKey();">
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{autoComplete.handleComplete}" update=":content" oncomplete="styleOnKey();"/>
    </p:autoComplete>
</h:form>

...

<h:form id="selectMenu">
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{autoComplete.strSelectedSearch}">
        <c:forEach items="#{autoComplete.lstSearches}" var="search">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{search}" itemValue="#{search}" />
        </c:forEach>
        <p:ajax event="change" update=":autoComplete:auto :content" listener="#{autoComplete.handleSelect(event)}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

...
```

And some Snippets of my backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "autoComplete")
@ViewScoped
public class AutoCompleteBean implements Serializable {

    ...
        public void handleComplete(SelectEvent event) {
            Logger.Log("complete fired");
        }

    ...

         public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event) {
            Logger.Log("select fired");
        }

    ...
}
```

Funny thing about this snippet, while using the .war-file with GlassFish 4.0 on Windows 7 SP1, the ajax-event on p:selectOneMenu (handleSelect) is firing. 
If you're deploying this code on a Windows 2008 R2 Server using Apache Tomcat 7.0.27, it doesn't. 
Anyone got an idea why this is the case? Is somebody able to reproduce this? 
The Rest of the Code works just the same. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated...^^

edit:
I managed to find the following StackTrace in the Tomcat-Logs:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.isAssignableFrom(ReflectionUtil.java:319)
    at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:185)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:257)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:53)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:804)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the following code-snippet inside of the :

```
...

<p:ajax event="change" update=":autoComplete:auto :content" onsuccess="#{autoComplete.handleSimulatedSelect(event)}"/>

...
```

Using the onSuccess-Attribute works with both Servers, but has anyone a reasanobly explanation for this?